# Hibernate and localized tables

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, localization, internationalization

I have a table holding Hotels which has a one-to-many relationship with table Services that holds all the services provided by a hotel. These services must be available in several languages, so for each service there would be X entries for X languages.

```
-----------             --------------------            --------------------
| Hotel   |             | Services         |            | ServicesLocale   |
-----------             |-------------------            |-------------------
| hotelId |-------------| serviceId        |------------| serviceLocaleId  |
| name    |             | category         |            | locale           |
| ...     |             | hotelId          |            | description      |
-----------             | ...              |            | serviceId        |
                        --------------------            --------------------
```

I'm using Hibernate plus Spring MVC to manage this info in my webapp. Currently I had mapped the ServicesLocale data into Services as a HashMap of (String locale, ServicesLocale), and I am always getting all the locale info when I retrieve a Service. But this does not work as desired since I have to list all services of a hotel sorted by its description in each specific locale.

So the initial solution was to retrieve service objects only for a specific locale, which makes the hashmap mapping useless (since I am only retrieving an object)

What's the best practice to map only specific locales into the domain object?

Note: I am only performing read-only operations, although a universal solution would be desired

EDIT: Posting some code.

Hotel:

```
public class HotelVO extends BaseModel implements java.io.Serializable {


    private Long hotelId;
    private String hotel;
    private String address;
    private String code;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;

    private Set servicesVOs = new HashSet(0);
}
```

Mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class catalog="bdd" name="HotelVO" table="hotels">
        <id name="hotelId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="hotelId" precision="4" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>


        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="hotel" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="hotel" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="address" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="address" />
        </property>

        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="code" type="java.lang.String">
            <column length="10" name="code" />
        </property>

        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="latitude" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="latitud" />
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="longitude" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="longitud" />
        </property>


        <set fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="servicesVOs" sort="unsorted" table="servicios">
            <key>
                <column name="hotelId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="ServiceVO" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Service:

```
public class ServiceVO extends BaseModel implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long serviceId;
    private CategoryVO categoryVO;
    private HotelVO hotelVO;
    private Long coordX;
    private Long coordY;
    private Long floor;
    private Map servicesLocaleVOs = new HashMap(0);

}
```

Mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class catalog="bdd" name="ServiceVO" table="services">
        <id name="serviceId" type="int">
            <column name="serviceId" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>

        <many-to-one class="CategoryVO" fetch="join" name="categoryVO">
            <column name="categoryId" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>

        <many-to-one class="HotelVO" fetch="select" name="hotelVO">
            <column name="hotelId" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="coordX" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="coord_x" precision="20" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="coordY" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="coord_y" precision="20" scale="0" />
        </property>

        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="floor" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="floor" precision="3" scale="0" />
        </property>

        <map fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="servicesLocaleVOs" sort="unsorted" table="serviceslocale">
            <key>
                <column name="serviceId" />
            </key>
            <index column="locale" type="java.lang.String" />
            <one-to-many class="LocaleServiceVO" />
        </map>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

LocaleService:

```
public class LocaleServiceVO  extends BaseModel implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long localeServiceId;
    private String locale;
    private ServiceVO serviceVO;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

Mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class catalog="bdd" name="LocaleServiceVO" table="serviceslocale">
        <id name="localeServiceId" type="int">
            <column name="localeServiceId" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>

                <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="locale" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="locale" />
        </property>

        <many-to-one class="ServiceVO" fetch="select" name="serviceVO">
            <column name="serviceId" />
        </many-to-one>

        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="name" />
        </property>

        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="description" type="java.lang.String">
            <column length="65535" name="description" />
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you post some code? especially your entities.

Comment: I just did. I had to simplify it a little bit so there might be some typos here and there.

Comment: What I would like to achieve is to map the specific serviceslocaleVO object into Service, without the map. Just like a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: A collection type should be used for one-to-many or many-to-one. what is your BaseModel ? do you use inheritance mapping?

Comment: No, BaseModel is just an empty class for future common methods. No relevance.
What I want is precisely not a collection, but a single object.

Comment: Then you need one-to-one mapping. Hotel have one then one services while service has only one locate? am i right? is that what you want?

Comment: @MichelReap I think you are confused in defining the relationship into entities . When you say that Services entity can have multiple  ServicesLocale entities (i.e one-to-many) then when you querying the Services entity then it will return all the List of ServicesLocale entities associated to that Services entity. and its your choice to select entity you want from collection.

Comment: No; services have many locales (one per language). But In my app, I want to retrieve the service object with a single associated serviceLocale, with correspondence with the user's current locale. So, I want to retrieve a single locale for this service, seamlessly.

Comment: @Ashish, I understand that. What I want to do now is to tell Hibernate not to retrieve a list, but a single object based on locale. Better than that, would be to just incorporate the ServicesLocale fields into the Service object, whith data fed from the proper locale.

Comment: @MichelReap to get single object based on locale you have to write your own method which will iterate the Collection of serviceLocale class and compare the local.and get the ServicesLocale object whose local matching with your local.

Comment: Well I've read about UserTypes allowing to do something along the lines... what do you think?